how to use CODY Chat to query local data from postgres with mcp in vscode
The Model Context Protocol (MCP) is an open protocol that enables seamless integration between LLM applications and external data sources and tools.
When I followed this tutorial step by step, I found that I couldn't directly query the data in the database. Instead, CodyChat can only tell me how to query. This is strange. How can I configure CodyChat or VSCode to achieve the same effect as Claude Desktop App?
query："How many products do I have in my postgres database?"

